# Scrolling issue in nested recyclerview in ViewPager2

Tags: android-viewpager2

I have a recyclerview (vertical) and in its viewHolder layout, I have another recyclerview (horizontal), and both of these are in viewpager2 fragment. And now when I try to swipe the horizontal recyclerview's items then i have to do it really slowly otherwise viewpager itself will scroll.